# Cycles Physics Unwanted Collision Chain Reaction

Tags: cycles-render-engine, physics

What I want to do is hard to explain so let me try. What I am trying to do is have a large number of cubes placed next to each other and all constrained to an empty to copy the location and rotation.(I have successfully done this)

I also want those cubes to be affected by physics such as gravity and collisions but they must first start deactivated. (again I have successfully done this)

But what happens is that when an object hits one of the cubes it causes a chain reaction hitting the other cubes, enabling the physics for all of the cubes, making them fall. How do I stop this?

Is there some threshold setting that I can change the maximum velocity or mass required to activate the physics?

I am sorry if I didn't explain it well enough and I will answer or clarify any questions. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Your question seems quite clear to me. If those cubes are actually touching, skin friction will obviously cause a chain reaction, even in the real world, so there has to be some space between them. I've played a little with it just now, and while I'm not ready to post a full answer, this may point you to a solution. I have not managed to get the space needed small enough to be (close to) invisible, but I did get it smaller by setting the shape to _Mesh_ and fiddling with the collision margin and the friction value.

Comment: Hmmm well I set the snap during transform to on and shift+D to copy the cubes. I didn't think doing that would make them to be constantly in contact with each other. And its completely fine when nothing hits the cubes but when it does hit even only one cube, it causes that cube to bounce into others enabling the physics for those and those cubes bounce into others enabling the physics for those exc.

Comment: OK I have bean messing around in blender and realized I forgot one important detail. I will be having cubes stacked on top of each other so even if we got your solution working when physics is activated for a cube on the top it will fall on the cube underneath it starting a chain reaction. So maybe there is a way to keep the physics

Comment: (Accidentally hit ENTER and it took me over five minutes to edit it) [Continuing]--So maybe there is a way to keep the physics for the cubes allowing only certain objects to collide into them but not allow the cubes to exert any forces on each other?

Comment: Hm. The game engine has both collision group and collision mask, by which you can make objects in the same group not collide with each other. In Cycles, however, you only have collision group, meaning that objects collide if and only if they belong to the same group. It's possible you could do what you're after by elaborately defining which cubes belong to which group. But you could also use the collision mask of the BGE, and record the sim as key frames, which you then use in Cycles.

Comment: Ok. I am new to blender so that's why I didn't know about that.  And why doesn't cycles have that option? Thanks for your help I really appreciate it! :)

Comment: Why Cycles and BI don't have that, I cannot say. Perhaps something to add a feature request for, or something that will be in 2.80, which, I believe, is going to be a major overhaul. I'll see if I can cook up a full answer for you, but I'm a bit preoccupied, so I may not find the time for it for a few days. If you're willing to share your .blend, so I wouldn't have to start from scratch, I might be able to do it sooner. You can upload it to [Blend-Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) then edit your question to include the link given to you once the upload is complete.

Comment: I don't have a .blend, all I did was set up a very simple simulation to make sure I could do what I wanted to do before investing a lot of time in it. I got it working in cycles but the only thing is that I will have to set up a very complex system of collision groups because I will be having hundreds even thousands of cubes. I think I got it figured out and it should work without any problems. As for game engine I cant use this for want I want to do. And take as much time as you need I totally understand. :)

Comment: Another consideration that will complicate matters. Objects that are set not to collide with each other, will simply pass through each other. Since you say you will have cubes on top of each other, those would fall right through the ones below, or trigger their physics, depending on which collision group(s) they belong to.

Comment: Yes I have thought of  this also. I suppose I could always turn on/off the physics for selected cubes at a certain time during the simulation using keyframes. I will just have to play around with it, see what works and what doesn't, I could also do a combination of using collision groups and manually turning on/off the physics. I think I understand it well enough now, thanks to you, to be able to make it work.